# VS2010 repeatedly showing animated icon

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010 is repeatedly showing this animated icon in the bottom right next to the "Ln" every 2 seconds.  And even if VS is minimized, it makes my cursor briefly show an hourglass every time.  Can someone tell me what this icon stands for?

[image: Unknown icon]

Edit:
Showing the icon during a build also.  Build icon is on left, mystery icon in middle.

[image: unknown icon in middle]

Comment: Are you building the project right now?

Comment: No, I just opened VS2010 and loaded the project.  Why would it be building every 2 seconds?

Comment: Don't know. Do you have some add-on that does that?

Comment: What type of project is this? And what language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon seems to be related to Intellisense.  I noticed that vcpkgsrv.exe was starting and exiting quickly over and over.  Although I had a large project.sdf file, Intellisense was not working in my project.

I found this KB from Microsoft related to VS2010 Intellisense issues on XP (I'm running XP).  When I installed the hotfix, the problem went away.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2526044